# Tools for determining convergence of non-specific sums.

Tags: convergence-divergence, summation

I've done a lot of googling and searching on here and I can't find what I'm looking for. So at risk of asking a duplicate question, I'm looking for some tools or methods to figure out if a sum is convergent or divergent. The sum in question is

$$\sum_{i=1}^{\infty} \frac{A_{i}}{\prod_{j=1}^{i} B_{j}} = \frac{A_1}{B_1} + \frac{A_2}{B_{1}B_{2}} + \frac{A_3}{B_{1}B_{2}B_{3}} + \dots$$ Where $A_i$, $B_i$ are integers $\geq 1$ for all $i$. I don't know what any value of $A_i$ or $B_i$ is specifically, and I don't really care what it might sum to, I just need to know if it converges or not.

That said, are there any tools or methods that anyone might recommend to help me figure this out?

Comment: You don't know anything about $A_i$ or $B_i$? Some examples are: If $B_i=10^{-i}$) and $A_i$ is constant, it will diverge but if $A_i=1$ and $B_i=2$, you will get the geometric series which is convergent.

Comment: Well, I know that $A_i$ and $B_i$ are positive integers at least, so no negative exponents.

Comment: Ok that's good and removes the mentioned issue with the absolute convergence in my answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think actually the ratio test might be helpful: It says that a series $\sum_{i=1}^\infty a_i$ is absolutely convergent (i.e. the sum of all $|a_i|$ is convergent) if $a_i\neq 0$ for all $i$ and there is a $c < 1$ and $N\in \mathbb{N}$ so that
$$
\left| \frac{a_{i+1}}{a_i} \right|\leq c \quad\forall i\geq N
$$

In this case we can calculate
$$
\left| \frac{a_{i+1}}{a_i} \right| = \frac{\frac{A_{i+1}}{\prod_{j=1}^{i+1}B_j}}{\frac{A_i}{\prod_{j=1}^{i}B_j}}= \left|\frac{A_{i+1}}{A_i\cdot B_{i+1}}\right| \overset{!}{\leq} c
$$

So you get the following criterion: If you can find an index $N\in\mathbb{N}$ so that for all $i\geq N$ the condition
$$
\left|\frac{A_{i+1}}{A_i\cdot B_{i+1}}\right| \leq c
$$
is fulfilled for a $c<1$, the series is (absolute) convergent.

### Examples

As mentioned in my comment above you can verify those two examples with the above criterion:

1. $A_i=a, B_i=10^{-i}$: In that case we have
   $$
   \frac{A_{i+1}}{A_i\cdot B_{i+1}} = \frac{1}{1\cdot 10^{-i-1}} = 10^{i+1} > 1
   $$
   for all $i > 0$, so the series is divergent.
2. $A_i=1, B_i=2$: We then have $\frac{1}{1\cdot 2} = \frac 1 2 \leq c=\frac 1 2$, so the series is convergent.

### Addition for negative values

You might get wrong results when including negative values. As the above criterion only verifies absolute convergence (which is stronger than convergence), you might get series that are not absolute convergent but convergent which will be not detected by this formula.

One example would be $A_i=1,B_i=-\frac{i+1}{i}$: This results in the alternating harmonic series which is convergent but not absolutely convergent. Indeed, the above test results into
$$
\left|\frac{1}{1\cdot\left(-\frac{i+2}{i+1}\right) }\right| = \frac{i+1}{i+2}
$$
and there exists no number $c<1$ so that $\frac{i+1}{i+2} \leq c$ for all $i>N$ because this fraction actually approaches $1$. This verifies that the series is not absolutely convergent (but says nothing about the convergence).

So you might find another criterion when handling negative values.

Comment: You said


If you can find an index $N\in\mathbb{N}$ so that for all $i\geq N$ the condition
$$
\left|\frac{A_{i+1}}{A_i\cdot B_{i+1}}\right| \leq c
$$
is fulfilled for a $c<1$, the series is (absolute) convergent.


How do you mean if I can find an index $N\in\mathbb{N}$, is that just for any $N$? Is that for all $A_i$, $B_i$

Thanks for the help!

Comment: This means that the condition doesn't need to be fulfilled for all $i$ but only for all $i$ starting at a specific $N$ (i.e. for all but finitely many $i$). For example take $A_i=10^i$ and $B_i=i$. Then the condition is
$$\frac{10^{i+1}}{10^i \cdot {i+1}} = \frac{10}{i+1}$$
That this fraction is smaller than $1$ is only true for all $i\geq 10$, so you can choose the index $N=10$ so that the above term is $\leq c=\frac{10}{11}$ for all $i \geq N$ (but not for the first $9$ indices)

Comment: It's actually interesting because this example shows that $\sum_{i=1}^\infty \frac{10^i}{i!}$ is convergent, i.e. $i!$ is growing much faster than $10^i$. The limit is approximately $22025.46579480671$ (by using the computer)